# Text in front and image at background at back inside the specific div

Tags: html, background-image

I'm trying to create a div where it has front text and background image.

So far, here's my basic html

```html
<div>
    <img src="@userImage" width="90px" height="90px" />
    <div class="footer-field">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Here is what the result I get.

[image]

But I want something like this from Microsoft word.

[image]

I hope somebody helps me. Thank you in advance

Comment: What CSS have you tried?

Comment: include the css that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `background-image` and a single html element.

```css
.footer-field {
    width: 190px;
    height: 190px;
    display: grid;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: red;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559157693-c34156e0f8c3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1350&q=80);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-field">Centered Text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with `position: absolute`

```css
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.image-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/600/400" alt="">
  <div class="image-text">Centered text</div>
</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/3z4q9mwn/)